# QuickSort - Worst case input example when pivot is in the middle position always

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

What could be a worst case input example for QuickSort if I pick the pivot in the middle position? I am thinking about equals elements like 3,3,3,3 etc. Or could it take it as worst case even if it would be already sorted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worst case for quicksort is when the pivot is at either end.  So having them arrive in sorted order is a worst case.

The only case for length 1 is `1` so it is also the worst case.

Otherwise we just increment every value by `1`, then insert a `1` into the first pivot.  Giving us `1` as a pivot, and the previous worst case as our next one.

So if we're picking the element at position `floor(length/2)` as our pivot, here are some worst case inputs generated this way.

```
1
2 1
3 1 2
4 2 1 3
5 3 1 2 4
6 4 2 1 3 5
```

And in general for length `n` it goes

```
n n-2 n-4 ... (1 2 or 2 1 as appropriate) ... n-5 n-3 n-1
```

Note that this is not the only worst case.  In fact for each pivot, it can be at either end and still be a worst case.  That means that for `n-1` pivots we have a choice to make, making there be `2^(n-1)` orderings of `1..n` that are equally bad.